# Why is an already defined function in Python not executing?

Tags: python, function

I am a Python NOOB and I have a Python function `game()` that executes perfectly, when the game ends I ask the player to play again. The `input` and `if` statement works (it prints my corny comment) but the next invocation of `game()` doesn't execute and the program ends? Why?

```
# Lots of cool game() code above here ^^^
game() #first invocation of the game() function, works great...
print ("Play Again? Y=YES, Any other key to quit")
if input() == "y" or "Y":
    print("oh yeah, its on!!!!")
    game()
else:
    exit
```

Comment: Because that's not how the "or" operator works.  Try `if input() in "yY":`.

Comment: Same result, the `print("oh yeah, its on!!!!")` executes using both `if input() in "yY":` OR (haha) `if input() == "y" or "Y":`, but the function still doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue likely with the following statement

```
if input() == "y" or "Y": 
    ...
```

Which is equivalent to

```
if (input() == "y") or ("Y"): 
    ...
```

You could fix that by preprocessing the string

```
while True:
    user_response = input('Play Again? Y=YES, Any other key to quit').lower() #convert to lower case
    if user_response == 'y': 
        game()
    else: 
        break
```

Compact

```
while input("Play Again? Y=YES, Any other key to quit").lower() == 'y':
    game()
```

Comment: `while true:` doesn't work, `true` is undefined. The compact statement works.

Comment: The real reason was I was such a general NOOB that I forgot to reset my global game variable to start state. *facepalm*

Comment: We expect you to know that Python spells it `True` with a capital T.